# How to access certain element in Angular DOM object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

How can I access signatures of, say 0 or 1 in the picture.

I know I can get to values by `objname.$$state.value` which returns the `[[], []]`, but how can I access say the signatures?

The list shown is what comes up if I click the Object shown in the console by `console.log(objname);`, Also, `objname` is a AngularJS deferred promise object I returned.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add below code your promise success code, so that the code shouldn't get failed.
You need to loop through the object `objname.$$state.value` then again the inner `forEach` will give you access to `signatures`

**CODE**

```
var allSignatures = [];
angular.forEach(`objname.$$state.value`, function(value, index){
   angular.forEach(value, function(v, i){
       allSignatures.push(v.signatures);
   });
});
```

Comment: that just makes an empty array :(

Comment: need to look at your code, probably you are executing this code before promise gets resolved...

Comment: While your answer was helpful, the problem was that the .then's first argument is a function and it has to take a parameter which I didn't set, rookie mistake - but you did answer the initial question, thanks.

Comment: @JahanzebKhan Actually i did mention in answer, you should run this code block, when your promise resolved, anyways glad to hear that it does helped you, Thanks :)

Comment: I meant I was writing .then(function () {...}) and I needed .then(function (objname) {...}) :)